# firebase and stripe return a link

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

So I am writing a firebase function. So far so good. I am returning the stripe function which is has a callback function where I am returning the `link` object. But in the client I get `null` as response.

This is my code:

```js
exports.handler = (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth)
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-auth",
      "Bitte melden Sie sich an"
    );
  if (!context.auth.token.email_verified)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Bitte verifizieren Sie Ihre Email."
    );
  return db
    .collection("userInformation")
    .doc(context.auth.uid)
    .get()
    .then(user => {
      if (!user)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "failed-precondition",
          "Nutzer wurde nicht gefunden"
        );
      const userData = user.data();
      if (!userData.stripeAccountId)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "failed-precondition",
          "Der Nutzer ist mit keinem Stripe Account verbunden"
        );

      return stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(
        userData.stripeAccountId,
        (err, link) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
          console.log(link.url +" +TEST");
          return link;
        }
      );
    });
};
```

So I think the problem is, if I could `.then()`the method of stripe, I could handle the return better. But how would I do it with that callback?

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are using Stripe-node (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node).
Stripe-Node returns promise for all the function calls so yeah, definitely you could use the `.then` syntax (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/StripeMethod.js#L45)

e.g.

```
stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(
        userData.stripeAccountId,
        (err, link) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
          console.log(link.url +" +TEST");
          return link;
        }
      );
```

Could be written in

```
stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(userData.stripeAccountId)
  .then(link => { // do something with link }
  .catch(err => { // handle your error }
```

Or in `async/await`

```
try {
  let link = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(userData.stripeAccountId)
} catch(err) { 
  // handle your error 
}
```

Comment: Okay, that works as same as before. I dont know where this comes from